# Google Map - Add a marker between 2 markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps

for my web application, I need to allow to add a marker between 2 markers.

I have an array of markers, and I push my markers when I create one.

My problem, I don't arrive to have my array working. I add the marker on the map with the right position, between the previous one and next one, but, how can I push in my array in the right index ?
I add between marker 1 and 2, so, the new marker must have the index 2, then, the old index 2 must have index 3....

`
function AddMarkerAfter(i)
{

```
  var lat = (markers[i].getPosition().lat() + markers[(i+1)].getPosition().lat()) / 2;

  var lng = (markers[i].getPosition().lng() + markers[(i+1)].getPosition().lng()) / 2;

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

     position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),

     map: map,

     title: 'Number ' + (i+1),

     draggable: true

}); 

    var l = markers.length;
    for (var j=i; j<l; j++)
    {
          markers[j+1] = markers[j];
    }

    markers[i] = marker;
}`
```

But, the result is catastrophic ... There is a way to "push" in the array ?

Thanks !

OH MY GOD ! 
I resolve my problem with this simple line :

```
 markers.splice(i, 0, marker);
```

Sorry !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for the array.splice() function ([example](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp)).

Comment: Yes, really sorry to not read correctly the documentation, I was sure splice was only used to remove elements. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Use the arrays slice and concat functions to split the array and rejoin with the new elemnent in between.

Version using ints:

```
var arr = [1,2,4,5,6];
var startarr = arr.slice(0,2);
alert(startarr);
var endarr = arr.slice(2);
alert(endarr);
arr = startarr.concat([3], endarr);
alert(arr);
```